# Tag to ignore HTML formatting code?

Tags: html, formatting, tags

I thought the `<code>` tags were supposed to ignore HTML like with BBcode, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Is there a way to achieve this in HTML so I can show code examples? I found a page about `<plaintext>` and `<xmp>`, but they're apparently deprecated, so what should I use? I've seen `<!-- -->` tags for comments, but those are completely hidden from view. I just need something to ignore tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, the only solution guaranteed to work everywhere is to escape the code manually.

```
<code>
  &lt;img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"&gt;
</code>
```

- Replace the `<` character with `&lt;`
- Replace the `>` character with `&gt;`
- Optionally surround your HTML sample with or without tags. (e.x. `<code>` or `<pre>`)

Comment: I already have that tag on my site. All it does is preserve raw formatting; nothing is done about tags within `pre` tags.

Comment: Could you give an example of what it is you're trying to achieve? Are you wanting the BB codes to actually format the text? E.x. Are you expecting [b]Bold[/b], to bolden txt, or just to be able to see the ```[b]Bold[/b]```?

Comment: What I meant with the BBcode part was that BB has `[code]` tags that don't format anything between them, and I'm looking for something like that so that when I type in something like `<img src="img.png" />` it doesn't actually show an image but the code I typed in.

Comment: Ah, misunderstood. Updated my answer.

Comment: and/or tags? I've never heard of those.

Comment: They're not actually tags, I meant with or without tags.